# Replacing a rejected iphone app, would it trigger a whole new review process?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

1. Will replacing a rejected iPhone binary cause a new review process to start from the beginning? As in suppose that it took 18 days to get a response and it was rejected for some reason, when replacing the binary, would it take at least another 18 days to get another review?
2. Is the reason given in the rejection email is the only fault they found in the application? I mean did it go through a full testing cycle and a report card was generated containing all the bug/faults/required modifications, or does the revision stop on the first unacceptable point and generates a report about it without continuing the testing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes. Maybe not 18 again, but you are going in the back of the queue.
2) No.  In  my experience, they will stop when they have found something.  I got a rejection for improper icon usage, changed it and resubmitted, then got a rejection for improper no-internet error handling.